# How to Cause a HyperLink to be Clicked or Activated from a JQuery Selector?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have two tables, one being a master and one being a child table for a database. There is a link in every row on the 6th column in the master table that refreshes the detail table with data for that row. The current row is highlighted. I have a button on the detail table that searches through each TR of the master table for a particular value in the first TD which holds the row number, and if the value equals the current row number + 1, the following code is executed:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var nextRownum = $(this).find("td[headers='COL01']").text();
    if (parseInt(nextRownum) == parseInt(currentRownum) + 1) { 
        $(this).find("td[headers='COL06']").find('a').click();
    }
});
```

$(this) being the TR. I know that this works somewhat, because I have the following code executing on page load...

```
$("td[headers='COL06']").find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){HighLight(this);});
});
```

...and when I click the button, the next row gets highlighted, but the page does not refresh; i.e., the hyperlink in my 6th column isn't being activated.

Any suggestions? Thank you; Matthew Moisen

Comment: Can you post the rendered html for the table as well?

Comment: Cant you just set `window.location` to whatever url the hyperlink would point to?

Comment: `a href` doesn't have a default click event

Comment: You can trigger an anchor click with `.click()`, or with `.trigger("click")`

Comment: @Archer  triggering `click` won't cause browser to open href of anchor

Comment: I suppose one of us should post the answer instead of saying what can't be done

Comment: Who +1'd Archer's comment - it's wrong

Comment: I can't post the rendered HTML, but it is being rendered by Oracle APEX so I don't think that is the problem. @charlietfl so click won't open href? When I click my button, the next row does get highlighted, so it is "clicking" it but its not refreshing the page.

Comment: No `click()` WON'T open href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.click` by default on an anchor. You could do this

```
window.location.href=$(this).find("td[headers='COL06'] a").attr('href');
// NB you won't ever need to .find().find()           ^
```

or you could give selected anchors a click event so that you can trigger them

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="icanhasclick">Woo</a>

$('a.icanhasclick').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href=this.href;
});

$(this).find("td[headers='COL06'] a").click();
```

Comment: Great! I placed the window.location.href=this.href; inside the $(this).click(function() ... after the highlight function.